# Is there an algebraic method to concat two numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I'm searching an algebraic way to concat numbers in base $10$.
Concatening two numbers is to put side by side their notations.

Let $c$ a concatenating function.

$c(2,2) = 22$

$c(8,9) = 89$

$c(11,0) = 110$

$c(14856,183) = 14856183$

I know we can easily do that using programmation, but it would be so elegant to do it with Maths. :)

I think that if $n(x)$ return the number of digits in a number $x$,
$c(a,b) = a * 10 ^{n(b)} + b $

But I don't know how to do it. Perhaps you can help ?

Comment: Erm. Shouldn't the exponent of $10$ depend on $b$ instead of $a$?

Comment: @xavierm02 Of course.

Comment: @egreg $n(a) = \lceil\log_{10}(a+1)\rceil\ (a>0)$

Comment: @peterwhy I always put the $+1$ in the wrong place.

Comment: Note: If $a=0$, (or you have leading zeros in $a$ or $b$), then you have to be content with those disappearing since you're looking for a formula that depends only on the numerical values of things and outputs a numerical value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all of the numbers are non-negative integers in base $10$, then the problem peterwhy describes can be fixed. We just need a special function to detect if $b$ is $0$.

A general trick to detect strict inequalities like $a>b$ versus $b>a$ is to involve the absolute value of the difference. In our case, $b>1/2$ if $b\ne0$, and $b<1/2$ if $b=0$. Therefore, we should consider the quantity $\left|b-\frac12\right|$. It equals $b-\frac12$ unless $b=0$. To make it easier to detect what's going on and avoid fractions, consider $\left|b-\frac12\right|-\left(b-\frac12\right)$. That's $0$ unless $b=0$ in which case it's $\left|-\frac12\right|-\left(-\frac12\right)=1$. This is perfect for us, because we need to add $1$ to the power of $10$ exactly when $b=0$.

Therefore, our final formula is $$c(a,b)=b+a*10^{\left\lfloor\log_{10}\left(b+1\right)\right\rfloor+\left|b+1/2\right|-\left(b-1/2\right)}$$

(Note: If you want something that looks weirder, you could also use $\left\lceil \left|b-\frac12\right|\right\rceil-b$ in place of the $\left|b-\frac12\right|-\left(b-\frac12\right)$ part.)

Comment: I just realized you might like the formula better if it had fewer fractions: $\left(\left|2b-1\right|-\left(2b-1\right)\right)/2$ will do the same job. You could eliminate all fractions if you're willing to replace $10$ with $\sqrt 10\ldots$

Comment: For a = 5 and b = 10, the result is 5010, which is wrong. I think the problem is that the ceil function should be the floor function, which would then give the result 510 for a = 5 and b = 10.

Comment: @MartinPekár Thanks! You're absolutely right that the ceiling should've been a floor. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @egreg , @peterwhy and @xaviermos2 I can now say that 
$c$ is concatening function for $a$ and $b$ natural numbers !

$c(a,b) = a*10^{⌈log10(b+1)⌉}+b$

Comment: The third example of yours has a $b=0$, and the $n(b)$ formula we gave does not apply to $b=0$.